# How to get a JWT from Google for my .NET Core Web API

Tags: google-oauth, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a mobile app (MAUI) which accesses a REST service (.NET Core).
I would like to secure the REST service using JWT and use OAUTH (first with Google) for authentication.  My understanding is the right way to do this is via the authorization code flow.

My goal is for my controller to get a JWT from Google after the user authenticates and then send this JWT to my mobile app so it can be used for authentication by my REST service.

First, is this a valid correct design?

Assuming it is, the problem I am facing is that I can only seem to get an access token, not an authorization code back from Google.

This controller method successfully redirects the user's browser to the google sign in page:

```
 [HttpGet("{scheme}")]
        public async Task Get([FromRoute] string scheme)
        {
            var auth = await Request.HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(scheme);

            if (!auth.Succeeded
                || auth?.Principal == null
                || !auth.Principal.Identities.Any(id => id.IsAuthenticated)
 

   || string.IsNullOrEmpty(auth.Properties.GetTokenValue("access_token")))
{
    AuthenticationProperties authenticationProperties = new AuthenticationProperties();
    authenticationProperties.RedirectUri = "/api/auth/callback?" + Request.QueryString.Value; // includes state
    // Not authenticated, challenge
    await Request.HttpContext.ChallengeAsync(scheme, authenticationProperties);
}

}
```

After the user authenticates, they are sent here.  I am expecting a "code" parameter in the querystring but it's not present.  However the auth.Properties.GetTokenValue() does give me an access token. But of course I can not exchange the access token for a JWT.

```
[HttpGet("callback")]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task Callback()
        {
            var auth = await Request.HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync("Google");

            var claims = auth.Principal.Identities.FirstOrDefault()?.Claims;
            var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.QueryString.Value);
            var token = auth.Properties.GetTokenValue("access_token");
            // Get parameters to send back to the callback

       }
```

My REST service is configured as follows:

```
var configuration = builder.Configuration;
 builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
    .AddCookie()
   .AddGoogle(options =>
   {
       IConfigurationSection googleAuthNSection = configuration.GetSection("Authentication:Google");
       options.ClientId = googleAuthNSection["ClientId"];
       options.ClientSecret = googleAuthNSection["ClientSecret"];
   });
```

What am I missing to get the authentication code from Google?  And if anyone has any examples of using this code to get a signed JWT from Google, that would be great.

**Update**: I have discovered that after Google authentication, the user is redirected back to localhost/signin-google with the authorization code as a query string there.   I understand that "signin-google" is the callback path defined in my GoogleOptions.  But how can I intercept this code here and generate a JWT rather than produce an access token which the middleware seems to be doing by default?  I tried to create a controller endpoint at this URL but it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure you're not? Can you check the console?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I don't see it in the Debug output, if that's what you mean.  Additionally, my AuthenticationProperties has the following items with these keys: .AuthScheme, .Token.access_token, .Token.token_type, .Token.expires_at, .TokenNames, .issued, .expired.  The access token appears to be the unsigned JWT (contains only one period, rather than two)

Comment: Google authentication will return the code when finishing the google authentication. Normally, we get it inside the google authentication option's callback event.

Comment: @BrandoZhang I have discovered that after Google authentication, the user is redirected back to localhost/signin-google with the authorization code as a query string there.   I understand that "signin-google" is the callback path defined in my GoogleOptions.  But how can I intercept this code here and generate a JWT rather than produce an access token which the middleware seems to be doing by default?  I tried to create a controller endpoint at this URL but it doesn't work.

Comment: I don't understand why you don't want to do that inside the  `.AddGoogle(options`  event to get the access token or else and store it inside the claims, then inside the each controller you could get it from the claims. This is also not inside the middleware, this is its service call back event during the authentication.